# Run AJAX script without event

Tags: php, ajax

I have

```
    <button type="button" onclick=" showUser($_SESSION["id"] )">Change Content</button>
```

Is there a way to do something like

`if(isset($_SESSION["id"] )) showUser($_SESSION["id"] );` ?

`showUser` is an AJAX script that prints something.

I want it to run without any button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    echo '<script>showUser('.$_SESSION['id'].');</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["id"] )) {?>
<script> showUser('<?php echo $_SESSION["id"];?>');</script>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing HTML, JS and PHP to one code. But yes, it's possible:

```
<script>
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']) {
  ?>
    showUser(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>); // do js function call to ajax function
  <?php } ?>
/* rest of js */
</script>
```